# Javascript output element from array as array with split using a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters

I am trying to create a function which uses a parameter which will split up items. The split part works, but the problem is when I try to use an item from an array, I get undefined.

```
var arrayItems = ["twenty two","thirty three","forty four","fifty five"];

function splitElement(arr) {
    arr.split(" ");
    return arr;
}

splitElement(arrayItems[0]);
```

Unfortunately this returns `twenty two` instead of `["twenty","two"]`

As a test, I tried this and it does return what I want:

```
function splitElement(arr) {
    arr = arrayItems[0].split(" ");
    return arr;
}

splitElement();
```

But what I want to do now is to grab any element from the array as a parameter and leave arr as the wildcard which can accept any input parameter for the output.

For example, if I did this:

```
splitElement("sixty six");
```

then it should return an array:

```
["sixty","six"];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to return the result of the split, since it doesn't change the original item.

**Note:** you're not splitting the array or an element (you pass an item from the array, but the function is not aware of that). I would rename the function to `splitString(str)`.

```js
var arrayItems = ["twenty two", "thirty three", "forty four", "fifty five"];

function splitElement(element) {
  return element.split(" ");
}

var result = splitElement(arrayItems[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.split` doesn't modify the original value, it returns a new array with the elements obtained by splitting the string. You need to store that array to use it or return it.

```
var arrayItems = ["twenty two","thirty three","forty four","fifty five"];
function splitElement(arr) {
    arr = arr.split(" ");
    return arr;
}

splitElement(arrayItems[0]);
```

Or, even simpler, just return the result directly instead of storing it in a variable:

```
var arrayItems = ["twenty two","thirty three","forty four","fifty five"];
function splitElement(arr) {
    return arr.split(" ");
}

splitElement(arrayItems[0]);
```

Comment: I already figured it out before you posted, but I will choose your answer (in a few minutes when it allows it) since it helped not only give the same solution as mine, but also explain why. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wow a lot of answers in moments. However, I solved it myself.

I made one mistake. What I needed to do was to define the variable in the function, then it will return the array.

```
var arrayItems = ["twenty two","thirty three","forty four","fifty five"];

function splitElement(arr) {
    arr = arr.split(" ");
    return arr;
}

splitElement(arrayItems[0]);
```

The only part I was missing was `arr =` before `arr.split(" ");`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for all elements and get an array of arrays:

```js
var arrayItems = ["twenty two", "thirty three", "forty four", "fifty five"];

function splitArrayElements(array){
  return array.map(item => item.split(" "));
}

var result = splitArrayElements(arrayItems);

console.log(result);
```